Series Solution of Laplace Equation in Spherical Coordinates
I am a physics student and this question was asked on the Physics stack exchange as well. I just want you to go through the derivation first. I was recently Studying Griffiths Electrodynamics after a long time and saw the Laplace equation there. Because it was my second time going over Griffiths, I decided to try to derive the solutions myself for fun purposes and because I wanted to apply the trick of the Power series to solve differential equations. I started by writing the Laplace equation in Spherical Polar Coordinates (Assuming no dependence on $\phi$)
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}\left(rV\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial V}{\partial\theta}\right)=0$$
This Laplacian was not taken from Griffiths but from Jackson, they Both just differ in the radial part. Now using the Method of variable separation,
$$V(r,\theta)=\frac{R(r)}{r}\Theta(\theta)$$
$$\frac{r^2}{R(r)}\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{\Theta(\theta)\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{d\Theta}{d\theta}\right)=0$$
Now the Angular part is very Obviously just the Legendre Polynomials. Then we are left with the Radial equation which is my main Concern. The book just describes a lazy method and just tells the solution. I wanted to solve the radial part equation using power series method. So my Focus is on the Cauchy's Equation
$$\frac{r^2}{R(r)}\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}=l(l+1)$$
So, I assumed a power series
$$R(r)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$$
and By substitution we get,
$$r^2\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)=l(l+1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$$
Which gives
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)a_kr^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}l(l+1)a_kx^k$$
Which means
$$k(k-1)=l(l+1)=\lambda$$
$$k^2-k-\lambda=0$$
Using Quadratic Formula
$$k=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4\lambda}}{2}$$
and by Substituting $\lambda=l(l+1)$ gives
$$k=-l,l+1$$
which do indeed Form the radial part solution. But there is a problem with this approach. We know that $l$ is a positive integer and this means that $k=-l$ is not possible since $k>0$. My Power series solution only contains the positive value of k. I came to know about Laurent series and people on physics stack exchange said that for the power series, my index can go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in case of power series. I tried researching about it and found myself to be stuck because it is heavily used in Complex analysis which I am not familiar with. So my question is as a Physics major, how can I understand Laurent series ,and the index problem I'm having with Cauchy's equation(That k should be greater than 0 but $k=-l$ corresponds to negative values). It will be really helpful if people from math's can help me with this problem. Your answer's are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
